# Argue that the sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $$a_n=n^2\cos(1/n)-n^2$$
Show that the sequence converges.

Now, I know how to use the formal definition of convergence but I am looking for simpler methods (i.e the tests for series). I found it to converge to $-1/2$ but I need some method to show that it actually converges. Same problem applies to the sequence (not series)
$$\frac{n^3}{n^2}-\frac{n^3}{(n+1)^2} $$

I know the process of finding the value as $n$ shoots off to infinity for this sequence would just be write it all under 1 fraction and divide by the biggest power of $n$. But I run into the same problem of how to argue that it does indeed converge.

Comment: Use the fact that $\cos(1/n) \approx 1 - \frac{1}{2n^2}$.

Comment: Bounded is not enough.  $cos(x)\to 1-O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes I realized. Has to be monotonic as well

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a_n=n^2\cos(1/n)-n^2 = -n^2 2\sin^2 \frac{1}{2n}\to -\frac{1}{2}, n \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

They are not similar problems. For
$$
\frac{n^3}{n^2}-\frac{n^3}{(n+1)^2},
$$
you just do a tiny bit of elementary manipulation to write it as
$$
\frac{n(n+1)^2-n^3}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{2n^2+n}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{2+1/n}{(1+1/n)^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2
$$

For the cosine, you need to use some property specific to the cosine. If you know that $\cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}2+o(t^4)$, you get
$$
n^2\cos\frac1n-n^2=\frac12+o(\frac1{n^2})\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0. 
$$
If for instance you know that $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}t=1$, you can do, from $\cos^2t-1=(\cos t -1)(\cos t+1)$,
$$
\cos t -1 =\frac{\cos^2t-1}{\cos t+1}=-\frac{\sin^2t}{\cos t+1}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
n^2\cos\frac1n-n^2&=n^2(\cos\frac1n-1)=-n^2\,\frac{\sin^2\frac1n}{\cos\frac1n+1}\\[0.3cm]
&=-\frac1{\cos\frac1n+1}\,\Bigg(\frac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}\Bigg)^2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-\frac12\times1=-\frac12.
\end{align}

Comment: The sequence with the powers of $n$ only was simple as I just had to manipulate and then divide to see that we get loads of $1/n$'s which of course converges to $0$ for $n$ shooting off to infinity. I know the limitproblem for $\sin(t)/t$ but not sure about the result $\cos^2(t)-1=...$ (some parentheses are missing).

Comment: Hello Martin. Somethings seems off as my CAS and wolfram is saying it is $-1/2$.

Comment: and not $1/2$ as a limit.

Comment: Yes, because $\cos^2-1=-\sin^2t$.